# php giving wrong answer when using time zone Australia/Sydney

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, dst

I am developing an website to run in Australia.

so i have set the time zone as follows.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
```

I need to calculate number of days between two dates.

I found a strange behavior in the month of October.

```
 $now = strtotime('2013-10-06'); // or your date as well
 $your_date = strtotime('2013-10-01');
 $datediff = $now - $your_date;
 echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));//gives output 5, this is right



 $now = strtotime('2013-10-07'); // or your date as well
 $your_date = strtotime('2013-10-01');
 $datediff = $now - $your_date;
 echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));//gives output 5, this is wrong, but it should be 6 here
```

after 2013-10-07 it always give one day less in answer.
Its fine with other timezones. May be its due to daylight saving. But whats the solution for this.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: you can use utc time and when ever you need you can apply the offset to display date-time in your region

Comment: Hmmm... if my interpretation is correct strtotime shouldn't manage timezone so then you would have to manage that yourself. Use DateTime($dateStr, new DateTimeZone($timezone)); instead

Comment: Actually, scratch that. 6 is correct. Why should it give 5? Daylight savings only kicks in at 3am on the 7th [see Sydney clock changes](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=240&year=2013)

Comment: Very good question, and illustrates why you should keep local calendar dates separated from instantaneous time in your thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why it says 5, and why this is technically correct

In [Sydney](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=240), DST begins at 2013-10-06 02:00:00 - so you lose an hour in dates straddling that.

When you call strtime, it will interpret the time as a Sydney time, but return a Unix timestamp. If you converted the second set of timestamps to UTC, you'd get a range from 2013-09-30 14:00:00 to 2013-10-06 13:00:00, which isn't quite 6 days, so gets rounded down to 5.

### How to get the time difference ignoring DST transitions

Try using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects instead, e.g.

```
$tz=new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney');
$start=new DateTime('2013-10-01', $tz);
$end=new DateTime('2013-10-07', $tz);

$diff=$end->diff($start);

//displays 6
echo "difference in days is ".$diff->d."\n";
```

### Why does DateTime::diff work differently?

You might ask "why does that work?" - after all, there really isn't 6 days between those times, it's 5 days and 23 hours.

The reason is that [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) actually corrects for DST transitions. I had to read the source to figure that out - the correction happens inside the internal [timelib_diff](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=ext/date/lib/interval.c;h=96867ba2b797aaa9a98858114cdc24d3b1563a03;hb=refs/heads/PHP-5.3) function. This correction happens if all the following are true

- each DateTime uses the same timezone
- the timezone must be geographic id and not an abbreviation like GMT
- each DateTime must have different DST offsets (i.e. one in DST and one not)

To illustrate this point, here's what happens if we use two times just a few hours either side of the switch to DST

```
$tz=new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney');
$start=new DateTime('2013-10-06 00:00:00', $tz);
$end=new DateTime('2013-10-06 04:00:00', $tz);

//diff will correct for the DST transition
$diffApparent=$end->diff($start);

//but timestamps represent the reality
$diffActual=($end->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp()) / 3600;

echo "Apparent difference is {$diffApparent->h} hours\n";
echo "Actual difference is {$diffActual} hours\n";
```

This outputs

```
Apparent difference is 4 hours
Actual difference is 3 hours
```

Comment: thanks dude, you got me. but what is the solution to this , how can i get 6 instead of 5.

Comment: posted code which gives the answer 6 - it was interesting to explore *why* that displays 6 too!

Comment: Great answer Paul.  Looking at the source code for `timelib_diff` that you referenced, am I right in thinking this only works when the two `DateTime` values have the same time zone?

Comment: I've clarified the logic used to decide whether it applies this correction.